# ORACLE SQL INQUIRY

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an oracle database  I am buidling a query and am unsure how to do a compare with the field I set as 'Created'

```
SELECT C.IS_AW_TITLE, A.PORTAL_OBJNAME, C.IS_AW_ACTIVE_FLG, 
(TO_CHAR(CAST((C.CREATEDTTM) AS TIMESTAMP),'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF')) AS 
CREATED,.....

FROM ..., (sysadm.PS_IS_AW_PG_DEFN C LEFT OUTER JOIN  sysadm.PS_IS_AW_SECURITY D ON  
C.IS_AW_GRP_ID = D.IS_AW_GRP_ID ),...

WHERE ( C.IS_AW_CREF_OBJ = A.PORTAL_OBJNAME
AND C.IS_AW_GRP_ID = E.IS_AW_GRP_ID...
```

the 'Created' field produces results similar to this example:  2011-09-26-11.22.31.000000

How would I include it in the query to say something like 'AND Created = to_timestamp(....., 2011-09-26-11.22.31.000000)?

Comment: Why have you busted these into these weird little chunks?

Comment: What is the datatype of c.createdtm?

Answer (score 0):

You have let's say declared (not sure whether term is appropriate, feel free to correct me) `created` field as `to_char`, so its type is `varchar2`, that means you cannot compare it with `to_timestamp`.

I see several ways to do such comparsion:

1. Leave field as is, and compare `CAST((C.CREATEDTTM) AS TIMESTAMP` with the date you need;
2. Define `created` as timestamp, i.e. remove `to_char`;
3. Compare `created` with `to_char(to_timestamp(...));

Which one is the best fit would depend on how you're going to use `created` field in query result. If possible, personally I'd choose option 2.